# Why nested functions are taking time too long compare to individual functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Database is PostgreSQL 9.3.6

In the below code snippet `all_funs()` is a nested function. If we run the function like this, it is taking very long.

```
create or replace function all_funs() returns void as $$
begin
  perform a();
  perform b();
  perform c();
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Here a(), b() and c() are the functions. All functions have `void` as the return type.

If we run the functions a(), b() and c() individually they are taking less time compared to all_funs() function. How can this be improved?

Comment: Please show a reproducible test case

Answer (score 1):

It is strange, but it is possible. I have some hypotheses:

If you do some very intensive IO operations inside functions, then you can hit checkpoint - for some larger function a checkpoint is more probable. Other variant - running in three independent batches allow to run autovacuum between calls. So some data can be vacuumed. Third variant - locking - locks are released at transaction end. So your code can wait on some lock.

Identifying the actual reason is not possible without more information. Try to check every statement inside these functions via [auto_explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auto-explain.html) (for example).